# Can you reassemble this famous quote?

Tags: cipher

This is a famous quote. If, after it has been decoded, you don't recognize it... then you fail.

9/6/21 | 20/18/21/6/22/15/16/10 | 20/10 | 16/15/21 | 16/21 | 6/3 | 21/21/2/9 | 19/16 | 16/21 | 6/3.

Slashes separate letters, pipes separate words.

Hint:

> It's scrambled... in more ways than one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quote is:

> To be or not to be, that is the question.

You can get this by:

> First reducing each number by one, then taking the corresponding letter in the alphabet.  Then rearranging the letters to form a word, then rearranging the words to form the quote.
>
>  E.g. : 9/6/21 → 8/5/20 → H/E/T → THE
>  20/18/21/6/22/15/16/10 → 19/17/20/5/21/14/15/9 → S/Q/T/E/U/N/O/I → QUESTION
>  ...